# Drop row and column of a dataframe that contains the non-zero minimum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a symmetric pandas dataframe. I want to drop the column and row that contains the non-zero minimum of the whole dataframe.

For example if you consider:

```
    A    B    C    D    E
A   0    2    1    5    3
B   2    0    7    4    8
C   1    7    0    10   6
D   5    4    10   0    11
E   3    8    6    11   0
```

I want to drop [row A, col C] and therefore [row C, col A] that contains 1 (minimum). So that my expected output is:

```
    B    D    E
B   0    4    8
D   4    0    11
E   8    11   0
```

What is the fastest method I can do that?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov added the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you could select from data from your dataframe without dropping with `loc`:

```
mask = ~(df ==1).any()
In [29]: df.loc[mask, mask]
Out[29]: 
    B   D   E
B  0   4   8
D  4   0  11
E  8  11   0
```

**EDIT**

To find the minimum value from dataframe except for `0` you could use twice `min`, first to find the minimum value through column and second to find minimum value of the resulted `Series`:

```
In [48]: df[df != 0].min().min()
Out[48]: 1.0
```

Then you could pass it in the above solution:

```
min_val = df[df != 0].min().min()
mask = ~(df == min_val).any()

In [50]: df.loc[mask, mask]
Out[50]: 
   B   D   E
B  0   4   8
D  4   0  11
E  8  11   0
```

Comment: Do you have a fast way to find the minimum of the whole dataframe (assuming it isn't necessarily 1)? I was thinking just use a for loop and np.argmin or pd.argmin.

Comment: Do you need to find an argument of the min value or min value?

Comment: @CharlieHaley I was expecting this to work. But for some reason it is not.

row_2drop = data.index[np.min(np.min(data[data !=0]))]

col_2drop = [col for col in data.columns if data[row_2drop][col] == np.min(np.min(data[data !=0]))]

Comment: @CharlieHaley you could try edited version of the answer